# gcc-4.8.2 make command error

Tags: linux, gcc, make

our server has "gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64"

I was trying to upgrade to "gcc-4.8.2" from source.

configure completed without errors

make command has reported following errors in config.log file :

> conftest.cpp:11:2: error: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
>
> conftest.c:10:25: error: isl/version.h: No such file or directory

how should I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-while-compiling-gcc4-5-3-on-rhel-x86_64-a-897915/

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar error here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57119

(See the config.log attachment)

Please provide more details (like your configure parameters)